# Не удается получить результат из кода C# в Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Я пытаюсь запустить простой код Hello World в VSC 1.22.1.

```
using System;

public class Hello
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

Он успешно завершает выполнение, но не производит никакого вывода, т. Е. - Hello, World!

Использую плагин "Code Runner".

**UPD:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Code Runner` не пользовался но... А вы уверены что смотрите в правильное место? На пример у OmniSharp есть [настройка](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md#console-terminal-window) куда выводить. Может быть `Code Runner` выводит не туда куда вы ожидаете

Comment: должен выводить в терминал (добавил скриншот)

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен, но там есть вкладка ВЫВОД(возле терминала). Может Hello world в ней?
P.S. Что у вас там снизу делает Unity?

Comment: этого я не знаю. Visual Studio Code работает ещё связки с Unity 5. Но это не должно влиять на роботу вывода верно?
По остальным окнам ничего нет кроме "консоль отладки" там инфа такая `UnityDebug: Initializing
UnityDebug: Searching for Unity process 'Unity Editor'
UnityDebug: Attached to Unity process 'Unity Editor (Unity)' (216)
UnityDebug: Disconnected`

Comment: @KillNoise Есть вариант, что так как подключён Unity то он весь log хапает к себе в консоль.

Comment: есть варианты как временно отключить?

Comment: Вот это я точно не знаю.

Comment: отключил все равно не работает :(

Comment: Очень странно. Я ни чем не могу помочь.